# error in visual web developer 2010 localhost:57315/insert

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Error   24  Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
 error in visual web developer 2010 after debugging plz help me.

Comment: when i debug the error is shown in visual studio and did run in the explorer.

Comment: Are you sure the project contains a reference to the specified assembly?

Comment: the issue is the .net frame work i was install in my computer, the error is remove but new error is shown which is configuration error which is not remove and i have no idea about it,how to remove this error?